# How to pass a string between two classes in android?

Tags: android, class

I have a main activity, which sends a string ( socket.out("back"); ) to socket.java.

```
public class socket { 

public static void out(String out){

    /*
     final String PREFS_NAME = "SAVEDIP";
 final String PREF_IP = "ip";
 String ip = null;
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
 ip = pref.getString(PREF_IP, "");
   */



 try {
  Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.2",8000);   
  PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   
      InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
  output.println(out);

  output.close();
  in.close();
  client.close();
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   Log.e("TAG", "UnknowHostExeption");
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("TAG", "IOExeption");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
  }
```

I want to chancge the IP address to variable "ip" (comment section). I have saved the IP with SharedPreferences, but cant read it. I tried the code in the comment, but eclipse underlines the "MODE_PRIVATE" part saying: "MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable".

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your socket class you haven't got context reference, easiest solution is to pass context object to out method

```
public static void out(String out, Context context){
```

Using this context object you can get SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I guess this ip address is unique through out the application, if so you can create your own Application class and you can save global stuff there.

Comment: Thanks for help. this was the solution for me :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows :

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

or

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

Comment: @user2156702 If it works for you then you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

In the both case the "getSharedPreferences" get underlined, with the error: "The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type socket"

What should i do with the context?

Answer (score 0):

```
in class A


SharedPreferences app_preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ProfileloginActivity.this);
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    // String text = textBox.getText().toString();
                     editor.putString("key",username);

                     editor.commit();
```

in classs B

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String username = app_preferences.getString("key", "null");
```